# Unable to launch spark-shell on windows 10: Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I am new to apache spark,

I have installed following on my windows 10 and getting below error when i am launching spark-shell, can anyone please help me here.

Java JDK version installed:
java version "9"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9+181)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+181, mixed mode)

i have set up environment variables "java_home", "hadoop_home" and "spark_home" as below:

JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9
HADOOP_HOME as C:\winutils
SPARK_HOME as C:\spark

Added following to Path variable
%SPARK_HOME%\bin
%JAVA_HOME%\bin

when i executed "spark-shell" from command line, i am getting following error. please help.

```
c:\spark>spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.

Failed to initialize compiler: object java.lang.Object in compiler mirror not found.
** Note that as of 2.8 scala does not assume use of the java classpath.
** For the old behavior pass -usejavacp to scala, or if using a Settings
** object programmatically, settings.usejavacp.value = true.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.exitingPhase(SymbolTable.scala:256)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20$lzycompute(IMain.scala:896)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.x$20(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble$lzycompute(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.headerPreamble(IMain.scala:895)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.preamble(IMain.scala:918)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1337)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.package$.stringFromWriter(package.scala:64)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$CodeAssembler$class.apply(IMain.scala:1336)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$Wrapper.apply(IMain.scala:908)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile$lzycompute(IMain.scala:1002)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.compile(IMain.scala:997)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.compile(IMain.scala:579)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:567)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:37)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:98)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:755)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on a Mac. I was able to resolve it by using Java 8 instead.

Comment: @Mohan using Java 8 resolved issue for you? Eric any reason why java 8 works and not 9?